# Implementing a directive which includes another html

Tags: angularjs, directive

I want to use the following directive. `<tabContent action="XYZ.html">` that will display me XYZ.html if the context.view is equal XYZ. So I've created the following directive:

```
.directive('tabContent',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:'<div ng-if="view==\'{{action}}\'" ng-include="\'{{action}}.html\'"></div>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.action = attrs.action;
        }
    }
})
```

is that the correct approach?
Thanks,
            Omer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if the directive name is `tabContent` so the html tag becomes: `<tab-content>`

Then I think there are some problems with your code, what's `view`? 
Then it should something like this:

HTML:

```
<tab-content action="XYZ.html"></tab-content>
```

JS:

```
.directive('tabContent',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:'<div ng-include="action"></div>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.action = attrs.action;
        }
    }
})
```

I removed the `ng-if` because I don't know what `view` is.

Comment: If I want to prefix action with a constant prefix "customer".
How can I do that?